# Is there a regex engine that supports "for each captured group" in replacement strings?

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

Here's my example. If I want to use a regex to replace tabs in the code with spaces, but wanted to preserve tab characters in the middle or end of a line of code, I would use this as my search string to capture each tab character at the start of a line: `^(\t)+`

Now, how could I write a search string that replaces each captured group with four spaces? I'm thinking there must be some way to do this with backreferences?

I've found I can work around this by running similar regex-replacements (like `s/^\t/    /g`, `s/^    \t/        /g`, ...) multiple times until no more matches are found, but I wonder if there's a quicker way to do all the necessary replacements at once.

**Note:** I used `sed` format in my example, but I'm not sure if this is possible with `sed`. I'm wondering if `sed` supports this, and if not, is there a platform that does? (e.g., there's a Python/Java/bash extended regex lib that supports this.)

Comment: "platform-agnostic" doesn't exist with regex.

Comment: Are you having any issues that the regexes you posted don't already solve?

Comment: @murgatroid99 No; I'm just curious if there's a solution that I can just run once. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl and other languages that support this feature *(Java, PCRE(PHP, R, libboost), Ruby, Python(the new regex module), .NET)*, you can use the `\G` anchor that matches the position after the last match or the start of the string:

```
s/(?:\G|^)\t/    /gm
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Perl. Maybe sed too, I don't know sed.
It relies on doing an eval, basically a callback.
It takes the length of $1 then cats `'    '` that many times.

Perl sample.

```
my $str = "
\t\t\tThree
\t\tTwo
\tOne
None";

$str =~ s/^(\t+)/ '    ' x length($1) /emg;

print "$str\n";
```

Output

```
            Three
        Two
    One
None
```

Comment: That's cool. It would work as long as the string to be replaced is one character long. Is the `x` a multiply?

Comment: Yeah, that's a Multiply operator in Perl that works on strings. Its like `for($i = 0; $i < length($1); $i++) { $replace .= '    '; }`. The regex will match at least 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea that came to me, this could also be solved with [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
s/(?<=^[\t]*)\t/    /gm
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Variable length lookbehind is not supported on %99 of the engines out there, otherwise it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a
   s/^\(\t*\)\t/\1    /
   ta' YourFile
```

Use recursive action on 1 regex with sed, it's a workaround